# Is it okay to have one table for storing images against multiple tables - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it okay to have one table for storing images against multiple tables? Or it is better to have a three separate tables? Only Office can have two images.

**Schema**

- `Inspectors` - InspectorID (PK), InspectorName
- `Offices` - OfficeID (PK), OfficeName
- `Staff` - StaffID(PK), StaffName

New `Photo` table (storing images in binary form for different table)

```
Photos - PhotoID (PK), PhotoData, InspectorID(FK), OfficeID(FK), StaffID (FK)
```

New schema

- `Inspectors` - InspectorID (PK), InspectorName, **PhotoID(FK)**

  ```
            or
  ```
- `Inspectors` - InspectorID (PK), InspectorName, **PhotoID_1(FK)**, **PhotoID_2(FK)**
- `Offices` - OfficeID (PK), OfficeName, **PhotoID(FK)**
- `Staff` - StaffID(PK), StaffName, **PhotoID(FK)**

Comment: Can any one photo be related to more than one Inspector, Office, or Staff?

Comment: Yes, office can have two photos.

Comment: I know, but can one photo belong to two offices?    Or to two Staff?   Or to two inspectors?

Comment: no, one photo will only belong to one entity.

Comment: In that case see my 4th paragraph that I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine but you don't need FKs in both the Photo table and the other tables.   Just put the PhotoID FK in the other three tables.

If you only have to worry about a second photo for offices, then adding a second PhotoID FK to the office table is fine.

If you want a more scalable solution, and/or if a single photo could be used for more than one of the other entities, then a [bridge table](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=many%20to%20many%20bridge%20table&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=many%20to%20many%20bridge%20table&gs_l=hp...0j0i22i30l4.0.0.0.4042...........0.OFPM4aZierg) might be in order.

OR if one photo can only ever belong to one entity, then you have a one-to-many in the opposite direction, and you can put the FK columns in the Photo table, and leave them out of the other entities tables.   You might also add an "Order" column to the photo table to specify the order the photos appear for the entity, or whatever else the front end might use that information for.

Comment: Staff and Inspector can have only one pic but each office is going to have two pics.

Comment: Do i need two photo id columns in office table as office can have up to two images?

Comment: No, you can have a PhotoCollection table and every office points to that one - m:n is a standard problem.

Comment: @TomTom: could you please explain in detail. Am i going to use the same PhotoCollection table for inspectors and staff? Also how can i distinguish b/w two photos for same office, i meant two photos will be used for different purpose for one office.